# MySQL: insert new column into a table with default value from other table

Tags: mysql

I want to add a new column to one table with default value from other table's column.

```
1st Table 'sensors'
-------------------------------------------------------------
id    sensorId      location    city    country     userId     
-------------------------------------------------------------

2nd Table sensordata
-------------------------------
id    sensorId     dataValues  
-------------------------------
```

I want to add a column in the sensordata table with the default value of location where sensorId is same.

How can I do that?

Something like this

```
ALTER TABLE  `sensordata` s ADD  `location` VARCHAR( 200 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 
    (SELECT location from sensors s WHERE s.sensorId = d.sensorId) AFTER  `dataValues`
```

Please don't tell me why I need to have duplicate data, there is a reason for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in 2 steps

**step1**

```
ALTER TABLE  `sensordata`  ADD  `location` VARCHAR( 200 )  ;
```

**step2**

```
update sensordata sd
join sensors s on s.sensorId = sd.sensorId
set sd.location = s.location
```

**Updated:**
This is what I have done and it works fine

```
ALTER TABLE `sensordata` ADD `location` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `dataValues`;

UPDATE sensordata d SET  d.location = (SELECT s.location from sensors s WHERE s.sensorID = d.sensorID);
```

Comment: I guess your answer is not complete  - updating existing rows may be necessary, but definitely not sufficient in emulating `DEFAULT` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql requires default value to be a constant in almost all cases - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html . 
You can write `before insert` trigger though to emulate `DEFAULT` functionality to some extent. Surely, trigger will affect only new rows, and you will need to manually update existing.